# Starting thrift server on one thread then connecting on another fails on linux

Tags: c++, thrift

I'm using Apache Thrift's C++ api. We call two functions in order: createServer() and then connectToServer().

createServer does this:

```
   auto serverProcessor = boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::TProcessor>(new ctsPluginServerProcessor(to_boost_ptr(_clientWrapper)));
   auto serverTransport = boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TServerTransport>(new apache::thrift::transport::TServerSocket(_serverPort));
   auto serverTransportFactory = boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TTransportFactory>(new apache::thrift::transport::TBufferedTransportFactory());
   auto serverProtocolFactory = boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolFactory>(new apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolFactory());
   _server = boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::server::TThreadedServer>(new apache::thrift::server::TThreadedServer(serverProcessor, serverTransport, serverTransportFactory, serverProtocolFactory));

   // create a new thread
   auto serverThreadFactory = unique_ptr<apache::thrift::concurrency::PlatformThreadFactory>(new apache::thrift::concurrency::PlatformThreadFactory());
   serverThreadFactory->setDetached(false);
   auto serverThreadRunner = boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::concurrency::Runnable>(_server);
   _serverThread = serverThreadFactory->newThread(serverThreadRunner);

   _serverThread->start();
```

connectToServer() does this:

```
  _clientTransport = boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TSocket>(new apache::thrift::transport::TSocket("localhost", 9091));
  auto clientProtocol = boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocol>(new apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocol(_clientTransport));

  NILVCTM_THROW_CHECK(clientProtocol, kInvalidConnectionToCTS);
  _client = make_shared<ctsPluginServerClient>(clientProtocol);
  NILVCTM_THROW_CHECK(_clientTransport, kInvalidConnectionToCTS);
  // _clientTransport->open() fails unless I sleep here
  _clientTransport->open();
  NILVCTM_THROW_CHECK(_client, kInvalidConnectionToCTS);
  _client->connectToCTS();
```

This code works on Windows without a sleep - on Linux it only works if there is a sleep where the comment indicates. How can I get this to work without a sleep on Linux?